# How do I turn keyboard LEDs on?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-backlight

I recently migrated from Win8 to Ubuntu22, but now the scroll lock key which I used for turning keyboard LEDs on doesn't work anymore. I've seen videos and tried the "xset led 3" and "xset led on" commands but both didn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 22 is headless Is that really what you are running?. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask a must read.

Comment: For most laptop models, the backlit function key is the F7 key. In the case of gaming notebooks, you should press the up and down buttons.

Comment: Please specify the right Ubuntu version in your question.